# Show code in scroll bar in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, scroll

Is it possible to start showing code in scroll bar in Intellij Idea? I mean when I see a minified version of my code in the scroll bar. I do not know how it is called. I remember it being called something like scroll map.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *Minimap*. There is no default view for this, but you can install the plugin [CodeGlance](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275-codeglance)

[image]

To install the plugin, go to `File -> Settings...` in the left tree, select `Plugins`, then `Browse Repositories`. Now search for **CodeGlance**, install and restart IntelliJ

Comment: How to enable the *Minimap*?

Comment: @iloveseven Usually, it is enabled by default. Otherwise, go to `File -> Settings...`. Select CodeGlance from the tree to the left and un-tick *Disabled*

Comment: I wonder after you use it, can you remove default scrollbar? Because it's useless now.

Comment: The original CodeGlance plugin hasn't been updated since early 2018, but there's an up-to-date [fork](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18824-codeglance-pro) that seems pretty solid.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you're looking for the IntelliJ CodeGlance plugin:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275-codeglance

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The CodeGlance minimap plugin mentioned in the original answers hasn't been updated since early 2018, but [CodeGlance Pro](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18824-codeglance-pro) is an up-to-date fork with many additional features.

[image: CodeGlance Pro screenshot]

Go to **Settings : CodeGlance Pro** after installation to move the minimap to the left side, hide the original scrollbar, change the line height, and more.